Lottie Animations are not getting rendered properly in Flutter why?
As the title suggest, lottie animations are not rendering properly for Flutter atleast I haven't tried other platforms.
Below is what the animation should look like.

Below is what is getting rendered.

Code:
Center(child: Lottie.asset('assets/lottie/glow.json'))

I have tried multiple animations primarily in .json format, also tried .lottie format too, same result, though I didn't try over the network, just because I don't intend to use load animations over network.

first Check the address you put in the pubspec.yaml like below:
  assets:
    - assets/lotties/

second the lottie animation mabey is short, and you cant see changes, set repeat value to true:
set

repeat:true

on Lottie, like this:
Lottie.asset(
   'assets/lottie/successful.json',
   repeat: true,
),


This solution does not work

Maybe this can help. It seems like there is a bug where lottie files with custom colors are not rendered properly.
